# JavaScript does not find id's in Django template

Tags: javascript, django

I'm developing an app in Django and I have this `feed.html` template that loads different sections:

```
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           {% for piece in pieces %}
                {% include "pieces/pieces_card.html" %}
           {% endfor %}
       </div>
    </div>
```

In this `pieces_card.html` I want to load an script that does a 3d visualization. I have done the next thing:

```
<div class="madeleine container" id="id-{{ piece.id }}"></div>
```

And the problem is that the JS script fails, it prints this error `MADELEINE[ERR] Target must be a valid DOM Element.`. 
I think that this is because it is loaded before the selected id is loaded, how can make this wait until this particular element is ready?

Here goes the JS

```
function showPiece(targ, piece){
    window.onload = function(targ, piece){
        Lily.ready({
                target: targ,  // target div id
                file: 'files',  // file input id
                path: '../../static/js/src', // path to source directory from current html file
        });
    };


    window.onload = function(targ, piece){
            var madeleine = new Madeleine({
                target: targ, // target div id
                data: piece,
                path: '../../static/js/src', // path to source directory from current html file
            });
    };
};
```

And in the `pieces_card.html`:

```
var url_objetivo = '{{ piece.file.url }}'
    console.log("==== " + url_objetivo)
    var id_objetivo = "id-" + {{ piece.id}}
    console.log("==== " + id_objetivo)

    showPiece(targ=id_objetivo,
                        piece=url_objetivo)
```

Comment: Can you post the JS too?

Comment: JS added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Remove `targ` and `piece` args from `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function(){ ... }
```

**Previous answer:**

This JS function argument syntax is invalid:

```
showPiece(targ=id_objetivo, piece=url_objetivo)
```

Try

```
showPiece(id_objetivo, url_objetivo)
```

Comment: The syntax is not the problem, I've tried as you comment and it returns the same error.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: The error is solved, but now just the last one of the figures is shown.